# How cpu core frequencies, percentage cpu and memory utilization, processing load and temperature affect app performance?

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, cpu, temperature, benchmarks

I am trying to benchmark two machines for my app.
Two machines differ mainly in their peripheral connections and have same processor, memory and secondary storage.

I did four different types of runs:

- running SINGLE instance of app at ROOM temperature on both machines
- running SINGLE instances of app at HIGH temperature on both machines
- running TWO instance of app at ROOM temperature on both machines
- running TWO instances of app at HIGH temperature on both machines

In below diagram, the green bars (both light and dark green) correspond to same machine M1 which runs Ubuntu 20.02 and blue bars (both light and dark blue) to machine M2 running Ubuntu 18.04. Light green bar corresponds to M1 when it ran single instance of my app. Dark green bar corresponds to correspond to M1 when it ran two instances of my app. Light blue bar corresponds to M2 when it ran single instance of my app. Dark blue bar corresponds to M2 when it ran two instances of my app.

I have logged:

- %CPU utilisation from %Cpu row of top command
- I have lived App's %CPU and %Mem utilisation from %Cpu column of top command

I am running exact same configuration of MyApp and there are no other user processes running on these machines, only system processes.

[image]

If you look at "Avg time take to process one unit of data" row, its clear that M1 always performs better than M2. Also, performance of both M1 and M2 reduces at high temperature.

But there are several confusing observations that I have doubts for:

1. For both temperatures, MyApp % CPU for M2 (light blue bar) is more than corresponding values for M1. However, it still takes more time to process one unit of data. Shouldnt it take less time when CPU utilization is increased?

   For room temperature:

   |  | M1 | M2 |
   | --- | --- | --- |
   | Avg MyApp % CPU | 321.75 | 421.2 |
   | Avg Time taken to process one unit of data | 26.08 ms | 43.13 ms |

   For high temperature:

   |  | M1 | M2 |
   | --- | --- | --- |
   | Avg MyApp % CPU | 318.97 | 426.05 |
   | Avg Time taken to process one unit of data | 29.45 ms | 38.67 ms |
2. Why single instance runs has more Avg MyApp %Mem for M2 than M1:

   [image: List item]

   while double instance runs has less Avg MyApp %Mem for M2 than M1:

   [image]
3. Are Avg MyApp %CPU and Avg MyApp %Mem only sensible metrics to evaluate MyApp performance? Are core frequencies and total %CPU metrics useless?

   a. Core Avg frequencies are useless because core frequencies are dynamically throttled based on temperature and power consumption. But they are not correlated to CPU utilization as can be seen from diagram. Am I correct with this?

   b. Avg total %CPU is useless because it does not correlate to MyApp's %CPU utilization. Am I correct with this?